# Перевод кода с pascal на с++

Tags: c++, математика, pascal

Дана задача:

Найти член последовательности, заданной формулой Bi=4*Bi-1, при i>1. Значения первого члена последовательности вводится пользователем.

Был создан код в паскале, решающий данную задачу, как он будет выглядеть на C++?

Пример кода:

```
function B(a:real;i:integer):real;
begin
if i=1 then B:=a else B:=4*B(a,i-1);
end;
var a:real;
n:integer;
begin
write('Первый член a=');
readln(a);
write('n=');
readln(n);
writeln(B(a,n):0:3);
end.
```

Comment: да точно также, только вместо `begin...end` будут скобочки фигурные `{}` и `var` писать не надо

Comment: Приведите вашу попытку реализации данного кода, тогда мы сможем указать вам на ошибки. В данный момент это выглядит учебным заданием.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сейчас опять заминусуют, но потерплю из любви к математике :)

```
double B(double a, unsigned int n){ return a*pow(4,n-1); }
```

Крутой язык C++, правда? :)

Comment: а проверка где?

Comment: @Komdosh Того, что i>=1? :)

Comment: ага, как без неё же

Comment: @Komdosh А ее и у ТС нет :( Только на равенство.

Comment: Но по заданию то есть :)

Comment: @Komdosh Лично я задание понял так, что гарантированно не будут вводиться данные `i <= 1`.

Comment: учитывая, что это учебное задание, скорее всего будут